# Android 11 DisplayMetrics

Tags: android, android-11

Another breaking changes from Android 11.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Tried to obtain display from a Context not associated with  one. Only visual Contexts (such as Activity or one created with Context#createWindowContext) or ones created with Context#createDisplayContext are associated with displays. Other types of Contexts are typically related to background entities and may return an arbitrary display.
```

I have a custom `RecyclerView` and this is the flow when the error occurred.

```
public AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

private void initView(Context context) {
        heightScreen = getHeightScreen(context); ...


private int getHeightScreen(Context context) {
        return RealDisplayMetricsUtil.getDeviceRealHeight(context);
    }

public class RealDisplayMetricsUtil {

    public static int getDeviceRealHeight(Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            context.getDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
        else {
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
        }
        return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }
```

The error started here

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            context.getDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

Comment: How are you creating your instance of `AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView`? What `Context` is being passed to its constructor?

Comment: @CommonsWare it is a custom view so the usage is via XML

Comment: I assume that you mean a layout resource. How are you inflating that layout resource? Have you tried adding some logging to determine what Java class the `Context` is that you are trying to use?

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I am using a Service Context here launched by a Fragment since the layout is used for overlay (floating) feature. It works on Android 10 and below, why is it not working with Android 11? I can't remember if there is a documentation regarding this breaking changes.

Comment: "why is it not working with Android 11?" -- they tightened the rules, apparently. It is probably with an eye towards multi-display devices, so apps stop assuming there is only one display.

Comment: @CommonsWare, then what can we do to resolve such issue?

Comment: Overall, floating windows are on their way out, and they are already blocked on low-end devices. So, perhaps you should be considering what to do that can get you away from floating windows, such as using bubbles instead. Beyond that, since `RealDisplayMetricsUtil` is going to have problems with split-screen, freeform multi-window, foldables, and other scenarios, perhaps you could do something else for your UI that does not assume a single display with a fixed size.

Comment: So `RealDisplayMetricsUtil` soon will be completely useless and will only be use for backward compatibility? Any other alternative?

Comment: "Any other alternative?" -- for your scenario? I have no idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare it seems that this issue only happens when trying to access `Display` properties with non-activity Context like Service since using it in Fragment works properly. My last bet would be getting the Display properties ahead of time and access its value via Singleton class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the code above makes any different since both are deprecated in Android SDK 31, thus I just removed the condition completely to fix the issue. This is not the final answer but it should work for a meantime. Free to add new solution here, I will mark it as the answer after reviewing and testing it.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
        return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```